# How to select item in ComboBoxEdit in Devexpress

Tags: winforms, select, devexpress

In code bellow I need select Item in `ComboBoxEdit` with `idFunc`.

How can I do this?

```
ComboBoxItemCollection coll = cbFunction.Properties.Items;
coll.BeginUpdate();

coll.Add("  ... select function ...  ");

foreach (var item in lstFuncCB)
{
    cbFunction.Properties.Items.Add(new ImageComboBoxItem(item.FuncName, item.idFunc));
}

coll.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the EditValue property of ComboBoxEdit control to the item.idFunc value you wish to have selected.

```
cbFunction.EditValue = lstFuncCb[3].idFunc;
```